# I am wondering that there is some way I can only pick the highest value of each row in MapReduce(Hadoop)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I got below the values which signifies title, month, and value(summation) of combination of title(key) and month(key) each. I would like to pick up only one row with highest value among title, month, and value, For example, "Fly 08(09,11) 4 or Go 06 45, as you can see in my real output. If it's possible, please enlighten me. If you have any doubts, let me know, I will try to clarify.

```
Fly,07,1
Fly,08,4
Fly,09,4
Fly,10,1
Fly,11,4
Fly,12,2
Gentle Ben,05,2
Gentle Ben,06,3
Gentle Ben,07,2
Gentle Ben,08,2
Gentle Ben,09,2
German aircraft guns and cannons,11,1
Go,04,20
Go,05,29
Go,06,45
Go,07,24
Go,08,28
Go,09,37
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send first column as key value to reducer and remaining two columns as value to reducer, so that all rows starting with same key should go to same reducer to get maximum value. In the reducer, iterate over each row and check the final value. If there is no multiple rows with max value there will be only one value in second column else append all those values. Below is the code for your knowledge.

```
public class MaxValueGroupedMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

@Override
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    String lines = value.toString();
    String[] val = lines.split(",");

    context.write(new Text(val[0]), new Text(val[1] + "," + val[2]));

 }
}

public class MaxValueGroupedReducer extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text>{

@Override
public void reduce(Text key,Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

    int max = 0;
    String val = null;
    Iterator it = (Iterator) values.iterator();

    for(Text txt : values){

        String st[] = txt.toString().split(",");
        int data = new Integer(st[1]);
        if(data > max){
            max = data;
            val = st[0];
        }else if (data == max){
            val  = val +"," + st[0];
        }
    }
    Text output = new Text(val+","+max);

    context.write(key, output);
 }
}

public class MaxValueGroupedDriver {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.set("mapreduce.job.queuename", "default");
    Job job = new Job(conf,"MaxValue");

    job.setJarByClass(MaxValueGroupedDriver.class);
    job.setMapperClass(MaxValueGroupedMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(MaxValueGroupedReducer.class);

    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    job.waitForCompletion(true);
}
}
```

Output for above dataset

```
Fly 08,09,10,4
Gentle Ben,06,3
German aircraft guns and cannons,11,1
Go,06,45
```

Comment: Sir, is there some way to pick up only one title(row) which was chosen with highest value among several rows?

Comment: yeah, you can do that .. you can set number of reducers to 1 and in you map class change the key to some dummy value in your context.write Eg :- context.write(new Text("A"), values)... This will insure, all rows will go to one reducer

Comment: I am sorry, I still don't get the point, Is it right to put only one more context.write ?

Comment: Sir, could you briefly explain the way again?

Comment: No, just replace the current context.write with this one.

Comment: Sir, when I only changed for a mapper, I got a bit weird output, don't I need to change a reducer class as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the values int the mapper, and in the reducer calculate the maximum value, like this:

```
public class MaxTileValue {

    public static class MaxTileValueMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String row[] = value.toString().split(",");
            if (row.length == 3) {
                String tile = row[0];
                String val = row[2];
                context.write(new Text(tile), new IntWritable(Integer.parseInt(val)));
            }
        }
    }

    public static class MaxTileValueReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

        protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int max = StreamSupport.stream(values.spliterator(), false)
                    .mapToInt(IntWritable::get)
                    .max()
                    .orElse(0);
            context.write(key, new IntWritable(max));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Job job = Job.getInstance(new Configuration(), "MaxTileValue");

        job.setMapperClass(MaxTileValueMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(MaxTileValueReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

The `MaxTileValueMapper` reads input file line by line. A key is the line number, and value is it contents. Maper splits the values, and writes tile name and its value to the context. Then `MaxTileValueReducer` recevies a key (tile name) and list of values written by mapper, and then calculates the maximum value.

Additionaly you should tune your input to be more *parsable*, for example use a csv format:

```
Fly,07,1
Fly,08,4
Fly,09,4
Fly,10,1
Fly,11,4
Fly,12,2
Gentle Ben,05,2
Gentle Ben,06,3
Gentle Ben,07,2
Gentle Ben,08,2
Gentle Ben,09,2
German aircraft guns and cannons,11,1
Go,04,20
Go,05,29
Go,06,45
Go,07,24
Go,08,28
Go,09,37
```

And the output of above mapreduce job over this csv is:

```
Fly     4
Gentle Ben      3
German aircraft guns and cannons        1
Go      45
```